# NextMethod not working after upgrading from R version 3.6.1 to 4.1.1

Tags: r

I wrote an R package a few years ago to go with a paper I was writing, called [PhiCor](https://github.com/Zabados/PhiCor). This was working fine, but I recently had someone contact me as they couldn't get it to work with their version of R 4.1.1.

This is the [most recent commit](https://github.com/Zabados/PhiCor/commit/c81b6eac1263aeb739db906e4c50ec6a17d89008) not working (so the code that isn't working can be accessed later:

> Error in NextMethod("CorIndex") : no method to invoke

I have upgraded R and I can replicate the error. But I do not know why it isn't working. This is where the error is showing up:

```
CorIndex <- function(InDataframe, speciesbinary,weighted, group, SquareID = NULL){
 speciesbinary = InDataframe[,speciesbinary]
 weighted = InDataframe[,weighted]
 group = InDataframe[,group]
 NextMethod("CorIndex")
}
```

I then have numerous other functions:

```
CorIndex.default <- function(InDataframe, speciesbinary,weighted, group, SquareID = NULL){

CorIndex.TargetVar <- function(CorIndexVarInput, targetgroup){

CorIndex.groupEqual <- function(CorIndexTargetVarInput){
```

In particular, the one that was being run that triggered the error was:

```
CorIndex.all.plusP <- function(InDataframe, speciesbinary, weighted, group, numberIteration = 1000, SquareID = NULL, toroidal = FALSE){
```

Which was being run with the example data I included in the package:

```
Species1_AllPhiPvalues = CorIndex.all.plusP(InDataframe = Species1, speciesbinary = "Species1", weighted = 'Proportion', group = 'HabId', SquareID = 'LocationID')
```

Comment: What is the class vector of `InDataframe`?

Comment: InDataframe is a data.frame.

 speciesbinary is numeric,
 weighted is numeric,
 group is integer.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand your method dispatch better. What does `class(Species1)` return?

Comment: I can reproduce the error with a toy example if I use input that is not an object (no class attribute). Also, the documentation says "NextMethod should not be called except in methods called by UseMethod or from internal generics (see InternalGenerics)." Do you get the error when you use the generic instead of the "all.plusP" method?

Comment: > class(Species1)
     [1] "data.frame"

Comment: CorIndex (InDataframe = Species1,
          speciesbinary = "Species1", 
          weighted = 'Proportion', 
          group = 'HabId', 
          SquareID = 'LocationID')

Gives the same error

Comment: CorIndex.default(InDataframe = Species1,
                 speciesbinary = "Species1", 
                 weighted = 'Proportion', 
                 group = 'HabId', 
                 SquareID = 'LocationID')

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: OK, I had overlooked the issue. You don't setup the generic correctly. You should have UseMethod in the generic.

Comment: Is the generic the "CorIndex.default"? So at the beginning have "UseMethod("CorIndex")?

Comment: No, the generic is `CorIndex `.

Comment: I suggest you read the relevant part of The R Language Definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Definition

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if I write any new R functions or rewrite PhiCor.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have simply done this:

```
CorIndex <- function(InDataframe, speciesbinary,weighted, group, SquareID = NULL){
  speciesbinary = InDataframe[,speciesbinary]
  weighted = InDataframe[,weighted]
  group = InDataframe[,group]
  #NextMethod("CorIndex")
  CorIndex.default(InDataframe,speciesbinary,weighted, group, SquareID)
```

Bit of a bodge exposing my incomplete understanding of S3. Seems to work, but a bit scruffy and I am not sure a problem won't pop up somewhere else.